# objects/ subject personal pronouns

Tags: pronouns, subject-verb-agreement

Just encountered the sentence:

> Do you wanna grab a bite sometimes. You know, just you and **I**.

I've noticed that my understanding of subject and object nouns is incomplete because I'd normally say

> just you and **me**

Could anyone please explain to me why 'I' is used and not 'me'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is whether "you and I/me" is the *subject* or the *object* of the verb.  Here, **we** are going to "grab a bite", so "you and I" is appropriate.  We could rewrite the sentence as:

> Let's *you and I* grab a bite to eat.

On the other hand, if "we" are the *object* of the sentence, use "you and me".

> She gave the money to *you and me* (to buy a house).
>
> This cake was made for *you and me*.
>
> Could you go get some lunch for *you and me*?

**However**, before you get too excited, and think you understand it completely ... unfortunately many English speakers don't know or don't care about this grammar, and instead use whatever sounds best:

> Let's go for a walk, just you and me alone.
>
> I think, you and me, we can build it together.
>
> [It's true we'll make a better day just you and me](https://youtu.be/M9BNoNFKCBI?t=312)

[Related article at ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me)

Answer (score 0):

Haha, I think "You and I" are the subjects of an implied sentence or clause, "You and I grab a bite", or (Do you want) "you and I to grab a bite".  But it's gonna be fun to hear other opinions...

My wife (Chinese) is learning English, and these cases and tenses make her crazy!

Answer (score -1):

Ask: "Who is going?"
Answer: "Just you are going and just I am going?"
Shorten the answer: "Just you and I are going."
Shorten the answer some more: "Just you and I."